# Multiple Resource Bundle in JSP message code

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 3. I have message bundles in following format :

message_en_US.properties
message_en.properties
message_USA.properties

In my JSP I am using :

Now, the order of finding the values should be en_US, then en then USA property files. 
how can i customize this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use configuration below. So, if you want to set default language you can use the second one.

In my src/main/resources I have mymessages_en_US.properties and mymessages_es_ES.properties

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <array>
            <value>classpath:mymessages</value>
        </array>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="es_ES" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you please explain how it will fall back to _USA properties ?